# Firebase cloud functions on an offline device

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I use **Firebase Cloud Functions** in a Flutter app. How does cloud functions behave when a device is offline in these cases? Is there any situation I can't reliably use cloud functions when the device is offline?

1. Trigger functions (`onUpdate()`, `onDelete()` etc)
2. Function invocations using function name

Comment: This might be in any situation, when being offline. Only server-side triggers will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an app is offline, there is nothing it can do to trigger any function.  Without network connectivity, the app has no ability to invoke a function directly, no make any changes to a cloud-hosted product that would fire a trigger on the backend.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. Are the triggers executed when the device is back online? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.  If you're talking about synchronized database product, like Firestore and Realtime Database, the trigger will fire when the synchronization happens.  That's not necessarily going to happen the moment the device gets back online, but it will eventually happen as long as the app is running, and the SDK is able to retry eventually.

Comment: thats awesome to know. thank you doug, would you be able to add this information on the answer too?

Comment: @DougStevenson in this case, does firebase `functions` invoke `onFailureListeners`? So that I can make a `Toast` that update failed.